# How to access the events properly when using jQuery.extend()

Tags: jquery, events

I am adding events to an extended object in jQuery using `jQuery.extend();`

Using jQuery 1.4.4, I was accessing an attribute named `__events__` and I could access this in a predictable manner in order to add my own event hooks.

Upon inspecting jQuery 1.5.1 objects, I noticed the creation of a random attribute on the object upon using the extend function.

The attribute has this format: `jquery151******************` (where * are numbers randomly generated).

Now I am blocked because I need to find a way to still access the same variable but because the name is random, I need a way to access it dynamically.

Does jQuery provides a way to do that? If not, what is the best way for me to add event hooks?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Why would you need to access an attribute to add events? jQuery has a [rich, published API](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/) for doing that.

Comment: Actually, I am manipulating the events already in store, which required me to access the internal events implementation details.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The numbers aren't as random as they appear, [they're the expando property, it's accessible via `jquery.expando` or `$.expando`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/data.js#L14).  The numbers are the timestamp (`Date().getTime()`) from when the page was loaded, in an effort to not conflict with any other attributes.

For example at the time of this answer, in this page:

```
$.expando === "jQuery151023621073900721967"
```

However, these are cleaner ways to do what you're doing, for example the `events` collections is accessible via [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/), like this:

```
var events = $("mySelector").data("events");
```

[`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/), [`.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/), etc all use this attribute internally, it's simply a key for where the element has data in [the `$.cache` object](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/data.js#L7), the value of that attribute is the key in `$.cache`.  For example, to get all data, events, etc for an element, it'd look like this in the raw form:

```
var data = $.cache[element[$.expando]]
```